# NACA Airfoil 0005.4

Tags: aerodynamics, airfoil

I have come across this NACA profile

> NACA 0005.4 mod

and it is not clear how to interpret this airfoil. Is this considered a 4 digit NACA profile? What does the number after dot mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a valid airfoil identifier. First two zeros indicate it is a symmetrical airfoil with no camber. The next two digits mean it has a five percent thickness to chord length ratio. The number after the decimal indicates a slight adjustment to the maximum thickness and location thereof. Instead of being 5% thick, this airfoil is 5.4% thick. There is quite a bit of very good info on NACA airfoils [here](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/airfoils/q0041.shtml). This airfoil is mostly used on helicopter blades, far as I can see.

Comment: And the "mod" addition means that is has some arbitrary changes applied to it which make the name almost meaningless. Remember that the [Lockheed C-141](https://m-selig.ae.illinois.edu/ads/aircraft.html) also uses a NACA 0013 mod. Heavily modded, with camber and all. The name just meant that Lockheed did not want anybody to know what really has been used.